# Operations with R14 (LR) in ARM Keil

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly, keil, mov

I have a problem using assembler in Keil uVision ARM.
I try set R14 register value with this inline assembler code:

```
__asm {
MOV R14, #Loop;
}
```

But the compiler says, that "undefined symbol R14". When I write the same code in .s-file, compiler says, that I can use just R0-R7 register in MOV instruction.
What is that? There are 4 bits in MOV instruction for register selection, it means, that i can select each of 16 registers for MOV, ADD, SUB etc. Why the compiler prohibits R14?

Thank you, sorry for my English.

Comment: Are you assembling the `.s` for Thumb mode?  Thumb has restrictions on which instructions can use r8..15.  For the inline asm, are you compiling for ARM at all, as opposed to AArch64?  Does it work with R0, like maybe it's just the wrong error message?

Comment: The upper registers in thumb-1 are *extremely* restricted. You can basically only copy between the registers, add another register without carry and without setting flags (no immediate), and compare with another register. R14 is actually exceptional, because you can `push` it too (can't `pop` it though, the corresponding stacked value goes to the program counter directly to return). In thumb-1, the upper registers are either special purpose (PC, LR, SP) or only useful as a very slightly faster fixed part of the stack, from which values can be copied to the low registers for use.

Comment: For the record, you can `pop {lr}` (R14) in ARM mode, but yeah in Thumb mode you can't.  I guess the register-set bitmap doesn't have a bit for `lr` (only `pc`) for pop.

Answer (score 1):

The inline assembler supported by the Keil compiler is not genuine assembly language, but it is [a similar compiled language](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124253408.htm). R14 does not exist in this language.

You can use a local variable in place of the register and let the compiler handle register allocation.